# Is my algebra correct here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

so I have the interest equation

$$P=C(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$$

and I need to solve for t. So what I did was divide to get rid of C first:

$$\frac PC=(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$$

then I took the logarithm to get nt on it's own

$$\log_{1+\frac rn}\frac PC = nt$$

divide by n...

$$\frac {\log_{1+\frac rn}\frac PC}n = t$$

Then the change of base to natural logs

$$t=\frac {\ln (\frac PC)}{n\ln (1+\frac rn)}$$

I was curious because Wolfram Alpha gave me a different answer so I wasn't sure if there's something I'm doing wrong that I should fix in the way I do algebra. I'm taking calculus next year so it's important that I do things correctly.

Comment: I would take the natural logarithm, or your favourite logarithm, immediately.  So no passing through the logarithm to a weird base. But the result would be the same, just a shorter calculation. Note that $\ln((1+r/n)^{nt})=nt \ln(1+r/n)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah yes, I forgot about the exponentiation rule. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algebra is fine, but use the natural logarithm first, so:

$$\frac PC=(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$$
$$\ln\frac PC=\ln[(1+\frac rn)^{nt}]$$
$$\ln\frac PC=nt\ln(1+\frac rn)$$
$$t=\frac{\ln(\frac PC)}{n\ln(1+\dfrac rn)}$$

Wolfram|Alpha sees the $C$ as the [Fresnel Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html) (look at the bottom  right of the top box for '[solve P=C(1+r/n)^(nt) for t](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20P%3DC(1%2Br%2Fn)%5E(nt)%20for%20t)'.

Comment: that's okay$$$$